# Get a last message from a discord as a client

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I want to get the last message sent in a discord channel that I am right now using Python ], but it is not mine server so I cant invite my bots to do it. What is the best way to get the last message? Is there any library that can do it?
Maybe Image recognition?
Thanks in advance

I want to get the last message

Comment: If you want to use image recognition then you'd have a screenshot of the chat, and if you can take a screenshot of the chat then you can just... read the last message... so doesn't that kinda defeat the purpose of automating it?

Comment: Maybe scraping the discord website? Note: this can be illegal, depending of the usage you do with the message and the publicity of the message (if it is a general chat of a big discord server it shouldn't be a problem since it is already pretty much public)

Comment: maybe try self botting an account in that particular. This is completely against the discord TOS. you can try to use the `on_message` event by checking the needed channel ID

Answer (score 0):

As i know , This Is Against of `Discord Terms` And 
And There Is No Lib For Doing These Works On `Discord` 
If You Can Get A `Webhook` , It Will Be Nice ! 
Otherwise , You Should Use `Ugly` Ways !

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).